# Phone number in listview

Tags: java, android

I use a ListView for text-items in my APP. But I have one problem: if a put a text with numbers, the numbers are convert to a link to show the phone dial screen. Can I disable this?

Comment: your problem sounds quite strange to me, could you please post your adapter here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining you list items as TextViews in a layout file then use `android:autoLink="none"` to prevent emails/urls/phone numbers etc from being shown as clickable links.

You should also be able to use `setAutoLinkMask (0)` on each individual TextView list item if you are creating/adding them manually.

I haven't tried it myself but I think that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this:
[image]

I have a standard ListView with a Image and a TextView (thats one item).

Comment: please edit your question instead of posting further information as answer.